# Нужен ли дефис?

Tags: орфография

Как по-русски пишется "on-line": через дефис — "он-лайн" или слитно — "онлайн"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слово находится в процессе освоения. Словарей много, варианты разные: слитно, раздельно, через дефис. Думаю, что приживется все-таки слитное написание. Очень уж много производных от этого слова, которые пишутся через дефис: онлайн-дискуссии, онлайн-вопрос,онлайн-бизнес. Два дефиса в слове - не в нашей традиции.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, при написании английских слов русскими буквами надо оставлять дефис, но это слово уже прижилось в нашем языке и стало писаться так, как оно пишется на массовых порталах, то бишь "онлайн".

Универсальный дополнительный практический толковый словарь И. Мостицкого говорит нам на это вот что:  *"рекоменд. онлайн, не рекоменд. он-лайн"*.